# Keras - Issues using pre-trained word embeddings

Tags: keras, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm following Keras tutorials on word embeddings and replicated the code (with a few modifications) from this particular one:

[Using pre-trained word embeddings in a Keras model](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html)

It's a topic classification problem in which they are loading pre-trained word vectors and use them via a fixed embedding layer.

When using the pre-trained embedding vectors I can, in fact, achieve their 95% accuracy. This is the code:

```python
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(embed_matrix), len(embed_matrix.columns), weights=[embed_matrix],
                           input_length=data.shape[1:], trainable=False)

sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAXLEN,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(35)(x)  # global max pooling
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(target.shape[1], activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(sequence_input, output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=2, 
batch_size=128)
```

The issue happens when I remove the embedding vectors and use completely random vectors, surprisingly achieving **higher** accuracy: 96.5%.

The code is the same, with one modification: *weighs*=[*random_matrix*]. That's a matrix with the same shape of *embed_matrix*, but using random values. So this is the embedding layer now:

```python
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(embed_matrix), 
len(embed_matrix.columns), weights=[random_matrix],
                        input_length=data.shape[1:], trainable=False)
```

I experimented many times with random weights and the result is always similar. Notice that even though those weights are random, the *trainable* parameter is still *False*, so the NN is not updating them.

After that, I fully removed the embedding layer and used words sequences as the input, expecting that those weights were not contributing to the model's accuracy. With that, I got nothing more than 16% accuracy.

So, what is going on? How could random embeddings achieve the same or better performance than pre-trained ones?

And why using word indexes (normalized, of course) as inputs result in such a poor accuracy?

Comment: When you say accuracy are you referring to the validation or train accuracy? Are the classes in target balanced? How are you structuring the model when there is no embedding layer?

Comment: I'm talking about validation accuracy. I'll investigate more to check out the balance between classes. But either way, it doesn't seem reasonable that random vectors perform better than pre-built embedding ones. This makes no sense to me right now.

Comment: Are you working in a very specific domain? Or one that is very different from the domain the word embedding were trained on? If so maybe a lot of the words are being embedded into very similar vectors and the model has a hard time telling them apart. Alternatively are you generating any augmented data before splitting train and test data? If so information about the validation data could be bleeding into the train data and the model could just be over fitting.

Comment: No, I’m just using a basic text classification data. Text corpora about different topics. Pretty standard.